# How can I use glVertexAttribPointer to attach two separate array to shader?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have two separate arrays. One which is used to persist the texture coords and then another one which is used to persist terrain vertices. Right now I'm trying to somehow attach to each other.

I've used the glVertexAttribPointer but it doesn't work.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

With this code I'm trying to generate ids.

```
GLuint VAO, VBO, EBO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
```

Here I'm trying to bind VBO and EBO to VAO.

```
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof newVertices, &newVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

/*
 * Use EBO
 */
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof new_indices, &new_indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Those binding works perfectly but problem which I have is here :

```
/* This attrib pointer is used to attach vertices */
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

/* This attrib pointer is supposed to be texture coords */
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)3);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

At the above, I generate VBO and EBO which are used to attach vertices, but how can I attach another array to glVertexAttribPointer without changing vertices data ? is that even possible?

Here is two separate arrays:

```
const int w = 100;
const int h = 100;

const unsigned int s = w * h * 5;
float newVertices[s];
unsigned int new_indices[s];

// This array is used for texture coords
float textureCoords[] = {
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f
};


int index = 0;
for (size_t row = 0; row < h; row++)
{
    for (size_t col = 0; col < w; col++)
    {
        float height = get_height(col, row);
        newVertices[index++] = static_cast<float>(col) / 10;
        newVertices[index++] = height*10.f;
        newVertices[index++] = static_cast<float>(row) / 10;

        // I tried to attach texture coords but this isn't work
        newVertices[index++] = textureCoords[0];
        newVertices[index++] = textureCoords[1];
    }
}

// This is used to calculate indices
int i = 0;
for (int row = 0; row < h - 1; row++) {
    for (size_t col = 0; col < w; col++)
    {
        new_indices[i++] = col + row * h;
        new_indices[i++] = col + (row + 1) * h;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the "two separate arrays"? Also `glVertexAttribPointer` should follow the `glBindBuffer`, cause this is the function that establishes the connection between the currently bound VAO and the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`.

Comment: hi @ybungalobill, I edit this post you can see two separate arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems I see in your code:

1. You wrote `(void*)3` instead of `(void*)(3*sizeof(float))`. Remember that the last argument to `glVertexAttribPointer` is the offset in bytes, therefore you need to account for the size of your datatype.
2. All your vertices have the same texture coordinates (1,1), so you'll sample the same color for the entire mesh. It's unclear how you want to use your `textureCoords` array, since it contains only four points. You need to specify different coordinates for each vertex of your mesh. One way of doing this is by:

   ```
   // I tried to attach texture coords but this isn't work
   newVertices[index++] = (float)col/w;
   newVertices[index++] = (float)row/h;
   ```

   However, since this is a simple transformation of your X and Z coordinates you can easily do that in your vertex shader without introducing a texcoord attribute.

Comment: Thanks, my problem was actually texture mapping.